# can I have different url for custom post type in frontend and backend?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

The question is straightforward. I have custom post type 'project'. In front-end for the project detail page I don't want 'project' to show in url. I mean by default project detail default url will be site_url/project/project_url but I want new url to be site_url/project_url.
I tried

```
           'rewrite'        => array(
                'slug'       => '',
                'with_front' => false,
            ),
```

but this cause url to be changed in both backend and frontend and also page named "Projects" is throwing 404 error.

Can this be done ? Any suggestions or help is welcome.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210/190376

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve it without using any plugin but I failed. So I used plugin 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/' and it helped me achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comments, in short, it's not the intended initial behaviour Wordpress had in mind. Only posts or page are supposed to display that behaviour. I've just made a couple of test. None of the answer properly works, as they all have impacts on some crucial functionality.

If you're not using *single-cpt.php* then the accepted answer could worked for you ***(eg: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210/190376)*** but then again I would suggest you avoid messing up the default permalinks structure.

In any cases, none of the example are talking about flushing rewrite rules upon modify the permalinks structure. Do your tests, tests all answers given in that post ***(eg: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/)***, and add the following to the top of your function.php file.

```
<?php

/**
* flush_rewrite_rules
* Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/
* Need to be removed before pushing to live.
* Can be replaced on live by: add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
*/
flush_rewrite_rules(); ?>
```

Making sure you're flushing every time is the only way to make sure your testing is accurate.

Comment: Yeah this solution is working only for parent data of custom post type and not child data of same custom post type.

Comment: You could use the default post type as the "Project" one and create a custom post type called blog as the regular post.